# Get name of generic type at compile time for annotation

Tags: java, generics, gson

Consider this generic class:

```
public class ListHolder<T> {
  private List<T> objects;
  [...] // non relevant fields
}
```

I'm using Gson to deserialize JSON response from a REST api. All lists of objects in the API look like this:

```
{"clients":[{"id":6493557,"name":"test", [..]}, {"id":6493557, 
[..]}]}

{"users":[{"id":6493557,"name":"test", [..]}, {"id":6493557, 
[..]}]}
```

The problem is that although the structure of the responses is the same, the keyword that starts the list has the name of the domain object. Gson uses the name of the field as keyword, or an optional `@SerializedName` annotation, but I don't know how to get the name of `T` at compile time.

I know that it's not possible to get it at runtime because of type erasure, but the annotation needs a compile time constant anyway, and the compiler does have this information at compile time.

I would like to use `ListHolder<Client>` and `ListHolder<User>`, which would work if I could do this:

```
public class ListHolder<T> {
  @SerializedName(nameof(T).toLowerCase() + "s")
  private List<T> objects;
  [...] // non relevant fields
}
```

Does `nameof()` exists? Is there another way to solve this problem? 
I can probably solve this with TypeAdapters and by customizing the deserialization but I have a feeling it won't be very nice.